# Lambert transform of monomials

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms

The Lambert transform of a function $f(x)$, is given by:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{e^{xt}-1}dx\;\;\;\;(\Re(t)>0)$$

We wish for a closed form of the transform :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{e^{xt}-1}dx\;\;\;\;\;\;(n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  \frac{1}{e^{xt} - 1} = e^{-xt} \frac{1}{1 - e^{-xt}} = e^{-xt}(1+e^{-xt} + e^{-2xt}+ \dots ).  $$
Thus,
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^{xt} - 1} dx = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-xt} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k xt} \right)dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-kxt} dx. $$
Now 
$$ \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-kxt} dx = \frac 1 {(kt)^{n+1}} \int_0^\infty  y^n e^{-y} dy = \frac{n!}{(kt)^{n+1}}.  $$
So
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^{xt} - 1} dx = \frac{n!}{t^{n+1}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{n+1}} =\frac{n!}{t^{n+1}} \ \zeta(n+1). $$